# PDO update query won't run but it runs on the sql studio

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm converting the queries from mysql to pdo to run on mssql and I have this query that is driving me nuts:

```
UPDATE cms_users SET lastlogin = GETDATE() WHERE id = '1'
```

For some reason it breaks when I run it through the PDO on  the PHP application but when I run it on the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio it executes.

This is the line where I'm running the query:

```
$this->db_val->query($Query,$this->db_val) or die("Error in Update Query <br> ".$Query."<br>");
```

And when i added some attributes to capture the error from PDO by putting this code in:

```
$this->db_val->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

I got this error:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column
>   name 'UPDATE cms_users SET lastlogin = GETDATE() WHERE id = '1''

Not sure which is the invalid column name, i tried putting the column names in `` but that didn't work as well.

UPDATE:

If this helps, I'm getting the same issue with a different query:

```
DELETE FROM cms_audittrail WHERE transactiondate <= '2015-02-26'
```

That also works on the sql studio but is not working through the php application. I am getting:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column
>   name 'DELETE FROM cms_audittrail WHERE transactiondate <=
>   '2015-02-26''

Comment: Did you forget the $ before `this->db_val->query($Query,$this->db_val) or die("Error in Update Query <br> ".$Query."<br>");`

Comment: Nope it's there. I'll add it into the question.

Comment: You've got `id = '1'` I assume that is supposed to be `INT` and should be `id = 1`.

Comment: @EternalHour I thought that this might be an issue as well but nope, still getting the same error.

Comment: Please show the Method `query($Query, $this->db_val)` and please also provide a `var_dump($Query)` from `query` method.

Comment: I think the query is interpreted as the column name. Meaning your `UPDATE...` is treated as the column name.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt here you go: string(54) "UPDATE cms_users SET lastlogin = GETDATE() WHERE id= 1". That method is a PDO method.

Comment: @wewesthemenace I'll look into that, not sure how I can find out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `$this->db_val->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`
, I assume the `$this->db_val` is the instance of `PDO` class or something extending it or wrapping it.

If it's the instance of `PDO`, why put the `$this->db_val` to the `PDO::query` method ?

It should just be:

```
$this->db_val->query($Query);
```

See **[PDO::query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)**.

Comment: What is `var_dump($Query)` @NaguibIhab?